# What will be the domain and range of $f(x)$ = ${7x-3 \choose 4x-2}$? [ ${\text{ }\choose \text{ } }$ stands for combination]

Tags: functions, combinations

At First, I thought the domain is the solution of the inequation $$7x-3\geq 4x-2$$  but the fractional values in ${n \choose r}$?      can't be counted.

Please help me out and forgive my writing problems of mathematical terms.

Comment: It depends on how you define the combination. I would define it by$$\binom{n}r=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(n-r+1)}$$in which case the domain is $\mathbb{C}$ without a selection of negative integers.

Comment: Yes, I defined it by nCr

Comment: What do you mean? You haven't stated a definition. That doesn't allow anyone to evaluate the combination.

Comment: I think as you wrote

 "but the fractional values in ${}^n \mathrm{ C }_r$ can't be counted"

I suppose you only want positive integers as $n$ and $r$? Am I right?

Comment: If you are equating it and getting to a fractional value of x, take the ceiling. So x ranges between 1 and $\infty$. You can find the range of f(x) from this.

Comment: yes , I want positive integers as n and r @Hrishab Nayal

Comment: Thank you @Math Lover. So you are taking the minimum value from r=n such that nCr becomes nCn=1 and maximum goes to infinity. Am I right?

Comment: In combinatorics, some people define $_n C_r$ as being $0$ when $0\leqslant r\leqslant n$ is not satisfied (since, when $r>n$ -for example-, there are no subsets with $r$ elements in a set of $n$ elements).  So, again, you need to make your definition explicit.

Comment: Do you define $n\choose r$ as $\frac {n!}{n! (n-r)!}$? Where all factorials are defined for whole number($\geq 0 $) inputs ?

Comment: @Taladris would it be sufficient if the OP defined choose as I said above or would it still need more explicit definition?

Comment: @Chris I do not see any value of x where f(x) can be 1. The min I see is f(x) = 6.

Answer (score 1):

When we define ${n\choose r}$ just for integer entries $n$, $r$ with $0\leq r\leq n$ we need
$$7x\in{\mathbb Z}, \quad4x\in{\mathbb Z},\qquad 0\leq 4x-2\leq 7x-3\ .$$
The first two conditions imply $x=2\cdot(4x)-7x\in{\mathbb Z}$. The third condition implies $x\geq{1\over2}$, which then also ensures $(7x-3)-(4x-2)=3x-1\geq0$. It follows that the domain of $f$ is ${\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$. The range (image set) of $f$ then is
$$f({\mathbb N}_{\geq1})=\left\{{(7n-3)!\over(4n-2)!(3n-1)!}\biggm| n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}\right\}=\{6, 462, 43758, 4457400, 471435600,\ldots\}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Well since you only wanted positive integers I suppose you would be dealing with only most basic combination function and only positive factorials.

Notice  we can constrain the question as $7x-3 \gt 0$ and $4x-2 \geq 0$ (since $n!$ and $r!$ have to be defined and n cannot be zero). Also since$ {n \choose r}$ has a term $(n-r)!$ note that $n \geq r \implies 7x-3\geq 4x-2$.

Or solving these we get respectively  $$x\gt 3/7$$ $$x\geq 1/2$$ and $$ x\geq 1/3$$

Since you need all three conditions to satisfy simultaneously you take their common solution range or intersection of solution.

Which gives $x\geq 1/2$ now put the values in expression and see that for $7x-3$ to be positive integer x must be $4/7$, $5/7$... similarly for $4x-2$ to be positive integer x should be $2/4$ ,$3/4$....

So the first common solution is $x=1$ So $x$ can be any integer $\gt 1$.

Similarly for Range we can plug in values $(x=1 \ \ \ \    x=2 ...)$ to get 6, 462, ...

Comment: Thank you. Perfectly got answer.